# How reference/instance of class work in the typescript

Tags: java, typescript

I was using the typescript in my project and I noticed that if the class properties and functions are the same, we can assign the instance of one class to another if both have the same properties and functions.

```
class A {
    getName(): String{
        return 'A'
    }
}
class B {
    getName(): String{
        return 'B'
    }
}
const obj1: A = new B();
const obj2: B = new A();
```

My background is `Java` so I'm confused how typescript is allowed to assign one class instance to another class reference which have the same properties and functions?

Even in inheritance, it works differently than the `Java`.

```
class OtherParent{
}

class Abc extends OtherParent{
}

class Def extends OtherParent {
}



abstract class MyParent {
    abstract getName(): Def;
}

class A implements MyParent {
    getName(): Abc {
        console.log('classe - B')
        return new Abc();
    }
}

class B implements MyParent {
    getName(): Def {
        console.log('classe - A')
        return new Def();
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, the `MyParent` class has a `Def` return type in the abstract method, but the class `A` is allowed to return a different type `Abc` that is not related(child) to `Def` at all?

I'm not comparing typescript with java, but the behaviour in the typescript about the class types are different or unexpected. That's why I'm confused and want to clarify what is going on behind the scene.

Comment: TypeScript is _structurally_, not nominally, typed - both types have a `getName` property whose value is a function taking no arguments and returning a string, so they're interchangable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so any class which have the same property and same functions name are interchangeable? Why typescript is allowed that? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Perhaps you should start with https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html.

Comment: This is an interesting question for someone with a Java background. @jonrsharpe - If you can write an answer, it will be helpful to the future visitors of this page. I am afraid comments get deleted and so can happen with your comment with the link.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash my comment might be deleted but _the TypeScript documentation_ will still be there - SO isn't here to mirror the official docs, and there are plenty of existing resources about TS for users to research before asking.